# Google Earth Screeshot and save as image

Tags: javascript

How can I take a screenshot of Google Earth's current view as an image using JavaScript/PHP. Or, if there is an API available for the screenshot where I can provide latitude and longitude it should the image. I tried GEWebBrowser and canvas element of html to save Google Earth View which was loaded in div or img element (tried in both) but did not get any success.

Comment: Folks, please explain shortly "why" when you down-vote a question.

Answer (score 2):

This link shows how to generate a Google Maps image based on Lat/Long values:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/imageapis/

```
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-15.800513,-47.91378&zoom=11&size=200x200&sensor=false">
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but i want screenshot of google Earth 3d which will be loading in browser showing 3d buildings. My requirement is i want the outside view of my hotel window like buidlings , trees , terrains etc

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). You can have an example code on this page : https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Screen-Capture .